# EditorConfig control File-scoped namespace declaration

Tags: c#, editorconfig, c#-10.0

I'm using C# 10 new feature `File-scoped namespace declaration`.

I have old code like this

```cs
namespace SampleCode
{
    public class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

I'm moving this code to

```cs
namespace SampleCode;

public class MyClass
{
}
```

But I have a bunch of warnings : `IDE0160: Convert to block scoped namespace`

How do I make sure people will have warnings only with old syntax ?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: VS2022 and VS Code

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To control the code style in editorconfig use this line :

To enforce this style

```cs
namespace SampleCode
{
    public class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

Add this line in `.editorconfig`

```
# IDE0160: Convert to block-scoped namespace
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = block_scoped:warning
```

To enforce this style

```cs
namespace SampleCode;

public class MyClass
{
}
```

Add this line in `.editorconfig`

```
# IDE0161: Convert to file-scoped namespace
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped:warning
```

Comment: Enforcing it in .editorconfig made the option to refactor the entire solution to file scoped namespaces avalible in VS2022 Preview, great!

Answer (score 19):

## Update 2022-01-27 (all scenarios setup)

JetBrains Rider does support the dotnet_diagnostic.IDE* syntax starting from version 2021.3.2.
This simplifies the setup for all possible scenarios into this:

#### EditorConfig

```
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped:error
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0161.severity = error
```

#### CSProj

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will cover all the scenarios. Original answer below. Still worth to read it.

---

There are several different settings which you should control based on your desired state, used IDEs and workflow.

They are described in [this](https://developers.mews.com/c-code-style-by-editorconfig-in-net-5-sdk-and-beyond/) article which I strongly recommend to read before you start building `.editorconfig` for your project.

Here is a summary for File-scoped, Block-scoped usings, respectively.

## EditorConfig/CSproj setup for File-scoped usings

---

### Visual Studio (error on violation)

#### EditorConfig

```
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0161.severity = error
```

##### Note

Syntax `option = rule:severity` will be [deprecated](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/44201), sooner or later.

---

### JetBrains Rider (error on violation)

#### EditorConfig

```
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped:error
```

##### Note

Rider doesn't support dotnet_diagnostic.IDE* syntax.

---

### CLI build e.g., CI/CD pipeline

#### EditorConfig

```
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0161.severity = error
```

#### CSProj

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

---

### Recommended setup

#### EditorConfig

```
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped:error
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0161.severity = error
```

#### CSProj

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

##### Note

Is the current .NET EditorConfig syntax a mess? **Definitely**.

## EditorConfig/CSproj setup for Block-scoped usings

---

### Visual Studio (error on violation)

#### EditorConfig

```
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = block_scoped
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0160.severity = error
```

##### Note

Syntax `option = rule:severity` will be [deprecated](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/44201), sooner or later.

---

### JetBrains Rider (error on violation)

#### EditorConfig

```
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = block_scoped:error
```

##### Note

Rider doesn't support dotnet_diagnostic.IDE* syntax.

---

### CLI build e.g., CI/CD pipeline

#### EditorConfig

```
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = block_scoped
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0160.severity = error
```

---

#### CSProj

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

---

### Recommended setup

#### EditorConfig

```
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = block_scoped:error
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0160.severity = error
```

#### CSProj

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: You are using both `IDE0160` and `IDE0161` - what is the difference?

Comment: @lonix IDE0160 = block scoped, IDE0161 = file scoped